# Grails 2.3 dependency management maven or BuildConfig

Tags: maven, grails, dependency-management

There is a lot of talk about maven being the dependency resolution engine of choice (or Aether more specifically). What is the result of this change from an application development perspective? Going forward am I meant to use an external pom file to capture my dependencies rather than BuildConfig? Do I run create-pom on legacy projects upgraded to 2.3x? Is there a recommended approach?

Comment: I can't imagine why anyone who has done proper research would choose Maven at this point

Comment: @BurtBeckwith I agree with you.  I think that most folks building Grails apps with Maven aren't making that choice at this point, but are working with a choice that was made in the past.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended approach is to express your dependencies in BuildConfig.groovy and let Grails take care of it from there.  You don't need to generate a pom file unless you are trying to integrate your Grails build as part of some other build (like a Maven build).  The normal thing to do, unless you have some specific reason to do otherwise, is to use the Grails build system which by default in recent versions will use aether to do the resolution, but that is largely an implementation detail and all you typically have to interact with is BuildConfig.groovy.

I hope that helps.